# AWS ElasticBeanstalk application loadbalancer Service role

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to create a new ElasticBeanstalk environment with an application loadbalancer with the following cli command: `eb create my-home-page --elb-type application`;

`INFO: Service role is required for application load balancer type enabled environments.
ERROR: Failed to launch environment.`

Even when using the administrator key, it gives the same error.

I already added the role aws-elasticbeanstalk-service-role and the permissions AWSElasticBeanstalkService (and AWSElasticBeanstalkFullAccess) and it still gives the same erro.

Everything works when i use the classic loadbalancer.

Answer (score 4):

For future reference, you'll need to add the service role to the command like this `eb create --service-role aws-elasticbeanstalk-service-role`

And while you're at it look at all the available options at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-create.html